# Find the equation of the plane that passes through the line of intersection of the planes...

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the equation of the plane that passes through the line of intersection of the planes $4x - 2y + z - 3 = 0$ and $2x - y + 3z + 1 = 0$, and that is perpendicular to the plane $3x + y - z + 7 = 0$.

This is what I got: $3x + 4y - z + 15 = 0$.

Can you please tell me if this is right?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my work:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Changed my answer to: 2x + 3y + 9z - 9 = 0

Comment: Can you explain the steps which led to your answer?

Comment: It does not appear right. The normal $(3,4,-1)$ to your plane is not perpendicular to the normal $(3,1,-1)$ to the plane $3x+y-z+7=0$.

Comment: Alright I changed my answer to: 2x + 3y + 9z - 9 = 0. Is that right?

Comment: You found a point $(3, 4, -1)$ that lies on both planes. This does not mean that the vector $(3,4,-1)$ is perpendicular to the line of intersection.

Comment: What about my new answer: 2x + 3y + 9z - 9 = 0?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Any plane passing through intersection of $4x - 2y + z - 3 = 0$ and $2x - y + 3z + 1 = 0$ is given by $$(4x - 2y + z - 3) + k(2x - y + 3z + 1) = 0$$ or what is the same as $$(2k + 4)x - (k + 2)y + (3k + 1)z + k - 3 = 0$$

This is perpendicular to $3x + y - z + 7 = 0$. Using dot product of normal vectors you can now find $k$.

**EDIT:** If you do calculations you will find $k = -9/2$ and final answer would be same as that provided in another answer namely $-2x + y - 5z = 3$ or $2x - y + 5z + 3 = 0$

Comment: Yes, that method is in my textbook but I don't understand it. Can you please explain how you got (2k+4)x ... ?

Comment: See the basic idea is that the new plane has to pass through intersection of existing two planes. Now the intersection of two planes consists of points which satisfy both the equations. Any point which satisfies two equations $(A) = 0$ and $(B) = 0$ also satisfies the linear combination $(A) + k(B) = 0$

Comment: One may also say that the points of intersection also satisfy an equation $(A)^{2} + (B)^{2} = 0$ but then it is not remaining linear and hence does not represent a plane. It is important to note that by linear combination we get a new equation which is linear in $x, y, z$ and therefore represents a plane which passes through the intersection of two planes.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The line of intersection of the 2 planes is parallel to

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ -2 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 3 \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -5 \\ -10  \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

**Hint:** The plane that you are interested in is parallel to $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2  \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and parallel to $\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$. Hence, it also is perpendicular to

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \\-5 \end{pmatrix}.$$

**Hint:** You found that the point $(3,4,-1)$ lies on both planes, hence lies on the line of intersection, hence lies on the plane that you are interested in.

Thus, the equation of the plane is $$-2x+y-5z = 3.$$

Comment: I am not familiar with that notation.

Comment: How did you get that last eqn?

Comment: @Ol'Reliable This solution assumes that you are familiar with cross products, which you said you are not. The idea is to find a vector which is perpendicular to the plane, and that is easily obtained from cross products. I noticed that you had [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518108/how-come-the-cross-product-of-two-planes-is-collinear-with-the-direction-vector) which deals with the cross product, hence I continued using it.

Comment: Why is plane passing through line of intersection perpendicular to the normal vectors of two plane?  I can't seem to wrap my head around this concept

Comment: @harambe The line of intersection lying on plane 1 is perpendicular to the normal to plane 1. The line of intersection lying on plane 2 is perpendicular to the normal to plane 2. 
Hence, the line of intersection is perpendicular to the normal vector of both planes, and in particular, to the plane spanned by these normal vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The answer $-2x + y - 5z = 3$  is the right answer. The simple way to go about it is to first find a vector which lies on the plane. This vector is parallel to the line of intersection of the two planes.  We therefore find the cross product of the two normals to the intersecting planes. We get the vector $-5i - 10j$  this is then crossed with the normal to the third plane to which  the required plane is perpendicular. This gives us the normal to the required plane which is $2i - j + 5k$.                                                       Then a point on the plane is obtained from the equations of the intersecting planes. Set say $z=0$. Solve simultaneously for $x$ and $y$.    Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach which gives us the same answer in the end. Let:

Let Plane P1 be: 4x-2y+z=3 with normal vector $\vec{n_1}$=[4 -2 1] 
$$ $$
Plane P2: 2x-y+3z=-1 has $\vec{n_2}$=[2 -1 3] as its normal vector.
$$ $$
Plane P3: 3x+y-z=-7 has $\vec{n_3}$=[3 1 -1] as its normal vector.
$$ $$
Plane P4: is the plane that we are seeking.
$$ $$

To find the line of intersection of P1 with P2, we can perform gaussian on those two planes:  \begin{bmatrix}2&-1&3&-1\\4&-2&1&3\end{bmatrix} 
which will give us a solution of the form: $$\begin{bmatrix}x&\\y&\\z\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}1&\\0&\\-1\end{bmatrix}+
t\begin{bmatrix}1&\\2&\\0\end{bmatrix} \qquad[1]$$ where t $\epsilon$ R.

Equation [1] is the line of intersection of P1 with P2 and has a direction vector equal $$\vec{v}= \begin{bmatrix}1&\\2&\\0\end{bmatrix}$$. To get the equation of the plane P4, we first find its normal vector by taking the following cross product:

$$ \vec{n_4}=\vec{n_3}\times \vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}\vec{i}&\vec{j}&\vec{k}\\1&2&0\\3&1&-1\end{bmatrix} =-2i+j-5k$$

So $\vec{n_4}$ is the normal vector of P4. 
$$ $$
Next, we have to find a point that lies on P4. Since P4 passes through the line of intersection of P1 and P2, P4 contains the line of intersection give by equation [1] above. So any points on the line of intersection will do. Indeed, pt (3,4,-1) as you found lies on the line of intersection (this can also be achieved by letting t=2 in equation [1] above)  and so does (1,0,-1). Suppose we choose (1,0,-1), then the equation of the plane P4 is:

$$-2x+y-5z=3$$
which is the same answer as given by others above as expected.

Comment: Why did you take the cross product of the normal vector to the 3rd plane and the direction vector instead of a vector on the line of intersection?